# Where can I find information for standard deviation and mean for real life data?

Tags: data-request

Can someone please point me to a resource where I can find the mean and standard deviation for real life data, for example the wingspan of an eagle or the weight of an elephant or anything meaningful. I can easily find data for the mean, but not for the standard deviation. I am trying to come up with questions about normal distribution for high school students. I can of course make up the numbers, but it would be better to have the numbers reflecting the actual facts.

Comment: What about finding the raw data (such as about crimes, animals, etc.) and calculating it yourself?

Answer (score 2):

There are many open datasets around. For instance, the [Iris data set](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Iris), and more searchable at [UCI Center for Machine Learning and Intelligent Systems](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets.html), from which you can compute your own average and deviation.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.asdfree.com/search/label/national%20longitudinal%20study%20of%20adolescent%20to%20adult%20health%20%28addhealth%29

and

http://www.asdfree.com/search/label/youth%20risk%20behavior%20surveillance%20system%20%28yrbss%29

have some biometrics (for humans)